# What is difference between two syntaxes in SQL?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from book;
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+
| id | title       | description   | maker_id |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+
|  1 | About Music | Music is Life |        1 |
|  2 | About Life  | Life is alone |        1 |
|  3 | Math Book   | Math.PI...    |        2 |
|  4 | Novel Book  | I am handsome |        3 |
|  5 | About Time  | TimeTravel    |        1 |
|  6 | I'm steve   | by steve      |        4 |
|  7 | hi          | hi            |        5 |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from book where id = if(true, (select maker_id), 0);
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+
| id | title       | description   | maker_id |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+
|  1 | About Music | Music is Life |        1 |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from book where id = if(true, (select maker_id from book), 0);
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Hi, I am Korean student.
I don't know why the case above works well and why the error is in the case below.

Comment: The error message says it all, really.

Comment: but (select maker_id) is subquery too.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, `select * from book where id = if(true, (select maker_id), 0);` is a very convoluted way to express `select * from book where id = maker_id` :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `select * from book where id = if(true, (select maker_id), 0);` the subquery `(select maker_id)` selects `maker_id` column value for current row (the subquery is correlated by fact) - so scalar value is produced.

In `select * from book where id = if(true, (select maker_id from book), 0);` the subquery `(select maker_id from book)` selects all `maker_id` column values from independent `book` table copy - so a rowset is produced if `book` contains more than 1 row, and error occures.

Comment: Can you tell me what 'current row' means?

Comment: @taejun The row from which `id` value is taken for testing in this condition.

Comment: You mean,
When the query like "where id = 'hi' and pw = 'hi' " is executed, System check the first record in the table to see if the value of the id column is hi and the pw column values is hi too, and check the second record to see if the value of the id columns is hi and the pw column values is hi too, and check the next record and check the next record in the same way...(continues). 
1. Does SQL engine will have like this process?

2. And the 'current row' you're talking about,
Do you mean each record being checked one by one here?

Comment: @taejun Of course inner implementation differs. But, looking from the outside, you should think that everything is happening exactly like this.

Comment: Differ?? When the query is executed, shouldn't you compare the entire record to find a record that meets the criteria? Am I wrong?

Comment: Please give me an answer for number 1 and 2... I don't know exactly what 'current row' means.

Answer (score 0):

While the first statement match id with maker_id on the same row

```
select * from book where id = if(true, (maker_id), 0);
```

This statement

```
select * from book where id = if(true, (select maker_id from book), 0);
```

Execute a second query (from the same table 'book') so the result is again all the rows.

This can be more clear if you add an alias to the tables:

```
select FIRST.* from book FIRST where FIRST.id = if(true, (select SECOND.maker_id from book  SECOND), 0;
```

Comment: 'match id with maker_id on the same row' ??

Does this mean When searching in sql, comparing the id and makerid values in each row?

Comment: Yes, this is what every join operation does

Comment: You mean, When the query like "where id = 'hi' and pw = 'hi' " is executed, System check the first record in the table to see if the value of the id column is hi and the pw column values is hi too, and check the second record to see if the value of the id columns is hi and the pw column values is hi too, and check the next record and check the next record in the same way...(continues). 1. Does SQL engine will have like this process? 2. And the 'current row' you're talking about, Do you mean each record being checked one by one here?

Comment: Every select (so even every subselect) has its own result set; so when you query the same table N times, database return N results. The result is fetched in order to match the condition you added in your statement and you can think about this process like a check on every resulting row (How every database engines really work is out of scope): the row under inspection in this process is what I called "current row".